# Codeigniter : Update function didn't update data into database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Data from view is accurately displayed before the update function but didn't update into database.

```
Public Function update_visitor_after_post( $v_id = null , $u_id = null){ 
    if($v_id = null || $u_id = null) {
        redirect(site_url() . 'visitorcontroller/edit_visitor');
    } else {
        $name           = $this->input->post('name');
        $father_name    = $this->input->post('father_name');
        $purpose        = $this->input->post('purpose');
        $contact        = $this->input->post('contact');
        $country        = $this->input->post('country');
        $province       = $this->input->post('province');
        $city           = $this->input->post('city');
        $address        = $this->input->post('address');
        $note           = $this->input->post('note');
        $updated_at     = mdate("%y-%m-%d");

        $update_users_table = $this->db->update('users',
            [
                'name'           => $name,
                'father_name'    => $father_name,
                'contact'        => $contact,
                'fkcountry_id'   => $country,
                'fkstate_id'     => $province,
                'fkcity_id'      => $city,
                'updated_at'     => $updated_at
            ],['u_id'            => $u_id]
        );

        $update_visitors_table = $this->db->update('visitors',
            [
                'address'        => $address,
                'purpose'        => $purpose,
                'note'           => $note,
                'updated_at'     => $updated_at
            ],['v_id'            => $v_id]
        );
   }
   redirect(site_url() . 'visitorcontroller/view_visitor');
}
```

Comment: Did any error message shows up? You can check it in your `log` directory (if you enabled it in your `config.php` file)

Comment: No it didn't give any error...just redirect to view

Comment: how i can enable it...please give me some hints

Comment: In the `application/config/config.php` file: `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;`

Comment: ok i will try this

Comment: And after you enable it, try it again, and look at the log file in `application/log/log-...php`. It can be a database problem, but for more information you need to see the log file

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your where condition to string as below

```
$update_users_table = $this->db->update('users',
            [
                'name'           => $name,
                'father_name'    => $father_name,
                'contact'        => $contact,
                'fkcountry_id'   => $country,
                'fkstate_id'     => $province,
                'fkcity_id'      => $city,
                'updated_at'     => $updated_at
            ], "u_id = $u_id"
        );

        $update_visitors_table = $this->db->update('visitors',
            [
                'address'        => $address,
                'purpose'        => $purpose,
                'note'           => $note,
                'updated_at'     => $updated_at
            ],"v_id = $v_id"
        );
```